# Grouping and staggering estimates with geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two "main" estimates `groupcent_rating` and `grandcent_rating` and I am hoping to plot them along with the model estimates that were stratified by the individual's R-EM status.

```
help.a <- data.frame(variable = as.factor(c("grandcent_rating", "groupcent_rating", "rem_grand", "rem_group", "white_grand", "white_group")),
                     lower = c(-17.1, -3.7, -25.6, -8, -19.6, -3.5),
                     b = c(-2.3, -0.8, 0.2, -2.4, -3.2, -0.2),
                     upper = c(12.2, 1.9, 25.8, 3.1, 12.9, 2.9), 
                     type = c("total", "total", "rem", "rem", "white", "white"))
```

Using the above example code, I can create the following plot with:

```
ggplot(help.a, aes(x = variable, y = b))+
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=lower,ymax=upper)) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

However, I am hoping to only have two variables on the y-axis (after the coord_flip) `groupcent_rating` and `grandcent_rating` and then have the White and R-EM estimates staggered (maybe jittered?) around those estimates but in a different color for White and REM.

My attempt is to use color in the aesthetics, but that just changes the color. I cannot figure out how I might jitter or offset these White and REM estimates by `groupcent_rating` and `grancent_rating` estimates.

```
ggplot(help.a, aes(x = variable, y = b, color = type))+
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=lower,ymax=upper)) + 
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: May I suggest making your data tidy first (before plotting it with `ggplot2`). Make the variables columns, then make each variable (column) ONE piece of information (i.e, separate out grand vs group into a separate column) and each observation or value (since you're using summary data) a row.  `ggplot2` is much easier to work with if you start with a tidy dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
library(stringr)
help.a$y = str_extract(help.a$variable, "grand|group")

ggplot(help.a, aes(x = y, y = b)) +
    geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, color = type),
                    position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]